# How do I insert $_POST values in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage with multiple questions which is being loaded from my database. Each question has a radio-box because users have to choose an answer from the value of 1 to 5.

Every time I hit the hit the submit button, it goes to a page with the link address showing the users answers (i.e. submit.php?12=1&14=2&15=3&16=4&17=5)

The first value representing the questionID and the second value is the score for that specific questionID.

**How do I insert those in my database?** I want to insert the questionID and the answer to a table which has a question field and an answer field.

```
<form action="../process/submit.php" >
        <?php
          $pin=$_SESSION['pin'];
          $question = mysql_query("SELECT question.question, question.questionID FROM   question");
          $index=0;
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($question)){

        ?>

        <div id="qpanel"><?=$row['question']?>
          <div style="float:right;">
            <div id="ratingbox" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="<?=$row['questionID']?>" value="1" >
              <div id="img1" title="Poor">1</div>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="<?=$row['questionID']?>" value="2">
              <div id="img1" title="Average">2</div>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="<?=$row['questionID']?>" value="3" >
              <div id="img1" title="Good">3</div>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="<?=$row['questionID']?>" value="4" >
              <div id="img1" title="Very Good">4</div>
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="<?=$row['questionID']?>" value="5" >
              <div id="img1" title="Excellent">5</div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
       </form>
```

Comment: *"How do I put $_POST Values"* - `<form>` defaults to a GET method if post isn't implied. The question is also unclear/too broad.

Comment: You write code and eventually end up doing an `INSERT ...` query?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Flagging?

Comment: @HendraNucleo flagging for?

Comment: OP's only paying attention to "answers", so it seems. Ok, I'm out.

Comment: unclear/too broad?

Comment: @HendraNucleo Yeah, too broad. No code to support the question. I'm off to lunch now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know it will happening :D

Comment: The page this goes with will print multiple questions. My problem is getting all the questionID and its answers

Comment: You'd need to show the "submit.php" script, your problem is there

Comment: my submit.php has nothing in it. Thats my problem, I could not think of any idea on how to get the value from "website.com/submit.php?12=1&14=2&15=3&16=4&17=5" to a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use name field in this format:

```
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="questionID[<?=$row['questionID']?>][]" value="5" >
          <div id="img1" title="Excellent">5</div>
        </label>
```

You will return in POST array with questionID and selected elements.

Comment: Yes, of course. But my problem is getting the value from all of the arrays created and inserting it to the database

Comment: @JayceeLimMariano
If you want insert this to database check this:

`if(isset($_POST))
{
  foreach($_POST["questionID"] as $questionID)
  {
    foreach($questionID as $answer)
    {
       $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `answers` (`questionID`, `answer`) VALUES ('".$questionID.'", '".$answer."')");
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: I will get back to this tomorrow, its already 1am here. Thanks @Labradorcode

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\evaluation\process\submit.php on line 5

Comment: It prompts that message and when I check my db, it has nothing in it. I had edited it as such so.

Comment: foreach($_POST["questionID"] as $questionID) { foreach($questionID as $answer) { $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO session_sheet (question, score) VALUES ('".$questionID."', '".$answer."')"); } }